# How to read webpages sending fake 404 header

Tags: php, header, http-status-code-404, web-crawler

Is there any way by which a crawler can read html from pages sending fake 404 header. I tried to get the page using `implode` and `curl` and `file_get_contents` still getting header 404 error.[similar SO reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921211/404-header-response-but-page-displays-ok)

Comment: how did you deduce it's a fake header?

Comment: @DoSparKot because webpage page is displayed

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use curl (or Guzzle) and actually add a user-agent along with the request. Some sites return 404's (or other errors) if no user agent is given (or blocked)