# Call to a missing endpoint in .NET Core produces 404 but also OK as response to Angular

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

Making a call to my backend, I forgot we changed the name of the endpoint, so I got 404. However, I noticed that the text provided was not *Not Found* as expected in such situation but rather *OK*. As the picture depicts, there's a lack of correlation between the (correct) status code in the error message and the (wrong) status name.

[image]

At first, I suspected that the backend used something like this forgetting to properly classify the status code of the response. Then, I realized that it's not possible, since the endpoint doesn't exist, so the contents can't be due to anything executed there.

```
//[HttpGet("coordinates/{id}")]
[HttpGet("coords/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetCoordinates(int id)
{
  ...
  // if (output == null)
  //  return NotFound(id);


  return Ok(output);
}
```

I need help diagnosing the issue and at the moment I'm uncertain if it's the backend that needs a touch or if it's something that occurs in Angular. The code for contacting the server is pretty straight by the book like this.

```
getCoordinates(id: number): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.http
  .get<boolean>(this.url + "coordinates/" + id);
}
```

The observable is then consumed in the component like this (the boolean might be surprising on GET but it makes sense in the actual case I'm working on).

```
onSave() {
  this.service.getCoordinates(this.id)
    .subscribe(
      suc => this.router.navigate([this.origin]),
      err => console.log(err));
}
```

Where is a likely point of miss-handling the response? Or is it, in a way I'm ignorant of a sort-of-OK state? I'm not sufficiently sure to make a judgement call here.

I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921211/404-header-response-but-page-displays-ok) and it only confirms mu hunch that something's fishy, not providing a hint as to what. Also, it's PHP so I'm unsure about the relevance.

Comment: Check the `"coords/{id}"` and `this.url + "coordinates/" + id`

Comment: @Tony We changed the name in the backend but forgot to update in the front. I know how to make it work - by setting the proper URL. What I wonder is **not why 404 occurs** - it's obvious and easy to resolve. I wonder **why the error says 404 OK**. It's the *OK* part that's confusing me. Thoughts on that?

Comment: Where is the picture of `404 OK`? Typically you will receive `404 Not Found`.

Comment: @RoadRunner Are you saying that you don't see the linked picture? Are you saying 404? Then I'm saying *OK*! See - this is how I feel about my error message... (Sorry, I couldn't resist the pun. Uploading the image right now.)

Comment: @KonradViltersten When you go to the Network tab inside Inspect, then hover over the status code of your request, what does it say?

Comment: According to `https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse` there is not link between `status` and `statusText`., so it's perfectly possible to get a `404` with text `OK`.

Comment: @RoadRunner Hmm... there are two. One 204 and one 404. First one is initiated by *zone-evergreen.js* second by *Other*. Actually hovering over the status says only the number, nothing more.

Comment: @Luuk It seems that `defaultStatusText` is set to `OK`?

Comment: @Luuk First of all, it seems so weird. Doctor: *can you breath?*, patient: *no, no, I can't, 404!*, doctor: *ah, OK, carry on...* Secondly, I'm curious if said situation, although possible, is caused by our bad design of the backend or frontend or both. I'm not sure about the details but I expected *404 Not Found* and I sense that we ducked up somewhere, missing a non-critical thing.

Comment: According to [`https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/response.ts#L183`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/response.ts#L183), you may need to just customize your `statusText`, otherwise `defaultStatusText` of `OK` will be returned. How you actually do that I'm unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *statusText: 'OK'* is RFC compliant, [see here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.4).

Yet it is possible to customize your response in a .NET core WebAPI with a middleware ([as shown here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)).

Here is an example of custom error handling in our app

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app,
        IHostingEnvironment env,
        IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider,
        VersionedODataModelBuilder builder)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandling>();
```

ErrorHandling.cs

```
public class ErrorHandling
{
    public ErrorHandling(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
    {
        // Error handling code here
        // For example if you want to set a specific statusCode
        context.Response.StatusCode = MySpecificStatusCode;
```

Answer (score 3):

As per [RFC 7540 documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.4),

> For HTTP/2 responses, a single ":status" pseudo-header field is
> defined that carries the HTTP status code field (see [RFC7231],
> Section 6).  This pseudo-header field MUST be included in all
> responses; otherwise, the response is malformed (Section 8.1.2.6).
>
> **HTTP/2 does not define a way to carry the version or reason phrase
>
> that is included in an HTTP/1.1 status line.**

Here is a discussion on the same: https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/599#issue-255768557.

> The `Fetch` spec simply defines `statusText` as the `status message`
> value, which unless otherwise specified is `OK`.
>
> For HTTP/2 it seems status message could be interpreted any number of
> ways:
>
> - empty string - because there is no reason phrase "OK"
> - because that    is always the default (would be weird to have a 404 OK though)    implementation defined
> - such as some default reason text for a    status code

Comment: @Konrad Viltersten : If you want to customize your statusText response, you can do it in the backend with a middleware. In your startup.cs Configure method, add ```app.UseMiddleware(ErrorHandling)``` and ErrorHandling is a class that you code to customize the errors

Comment: @bmtheo Got it. In fact, I believe that what you just mentioned **actually is** the answer to my question. Now, the others gave great info as to why, which was also part of my question but I'd like you to repost that as an answer. And if you throw in a link or two and a short sample of the process, there's a green check waiting for you. (I just followed your advice implementing a **very** crude error manager that stops the "OK".)